# Task<T>.Factory.StartNew in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task

I'm stuck with a problem. I need help...

In general, I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. When a user clicks on "Save" button, I run some code in a new created task. I need to know the result of operation, so I return the instance of my class ChangesMade. Then I serialze the object to JSON format and pass to a view. Then I check if result is true, I open an url in a new window.

So, in my controller I have the following:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(here some parameters) 
{ 
    var changes = await _model.SaveAsync(some parameters); 
    return NewtownJson(changes); 
}
```

The main saving logic is the following:

```
public async Task<ChangesMade> SaveAsync(some parameters here)
{
    var data = (await _model.GetData(some parameter)).ToList();

    // create a task of ChangesMade that contains public bool property MemoAdded 
    // that I need to pass to a view to know the result of operation
    var task = Task<ChangesMade>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ChangesMade changes = new ChangesMade();
        try
        {
            using (var tr = new TransactionScope())
            {
                // some code here omitted for simplicity…

                // if (someCondition == true) changes.MemoAdded = true;                 

                tr.Complete();
            }

            return changes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }                
    });

    try
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        string msg = "";
        msg= ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions
                    .Where(e => e != null)
                    .Select(e => e.Message)
                    .Aggregate(msg, (current, message) => current + " " + message + ";")
                    .TrimEnd(';');
        throw new Exception(msg);               
    }

    return task.Result;
}
```

I publish the project on two sites on IIS. The first works fine. But the second  doesn't - by some reason, it always returns changes.MemoAdded false to the view.

I can't find out a reason of that. I don't have a clue what to do ...

Comment: don't do that just make it a sync method and be done.

Comment: I propose to not only check for AggregateException, by the way

Comment: I don't have any exception - the code inside of TransactionScope runs ok.

Comment: In general if one deployment is working and another isn't you likely have some kind of contention / configuration issue. Your best bet is to setup a [Remote Debugging Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging) and see excatly what's happening. On another note though spooling up a background `Task` in asp.net is often a bad practice. Also, there's no good reason to be using `Task.Factory.StartNew` here, you need to be using the `async` api with whatever db access your using.

Comment: Finally, since your method is already `async` then `await` the `Task` instead of the blocking and potentially deadlocking `.Wait()` & `.Result`.

Comment: I already have an 'await' in SaveAsync method (I updated the code)

Comment: First [Don't use `StartNew()`, just use `Task.Run()`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).  Secondly, the correct code would be to `await` the `Task.Run()`.  What you're doing is definitely bad bad await/async stuff.  Thirdly, you shouldn't be doing background tasks via `Task.Run()` in this instance (asp.net), you're just wasting another thread for literally no reason.